# Can spring boot run on google standard app engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-boot

SpringBoot application can be deployed to Google Flex App Engine.

But when I try to deploy to Google Standard App Engine, an exception will be thrown out:

> [INFO] GCLOUD: 2018-06-11
>   23:04:06.517:WARN:oeja.ClassInheritanceHandler:qtp249515771-16: 
>   [INFO] GCLOUD: java.lang.NullPointerException [INFO] GCLOUD:  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936)
>   [INFO] GCLOUD:    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ClassInheritanceHandler.addToInheritanceMap(ClassInheritanceHandler.java:72)
>   [INFO] GCLOUD:    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ClassInheritanceHandler.handle(ClassInheritanceHandler.java:58)
>   [INFO] GCLOUD:    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser$MyClassVisitor.visit(AnnotationParser.java:476)
>   [INFO] GCLOUD:    at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:650) [INFO]
>   GCLOUD:   at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:525)
>   [INFO] GCLOUD:    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:978)
>   [INFO] GCLOUD:    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:958)
>   [INFO] GCLOUD:    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:902)
>   [INFO] GCLOUD:    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:851)
>   [INFO] GCLOUD:    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:163)
>   [INFO] GCLOUD:    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:546)
>   [INFO] GCLOUD:    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
>   [INFO] GCLOUD:    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
>   [INFO] GCLOUD:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [INFO]
>   GCLOUD: 2018-06-11
>   23:04:06.669:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanning elapsed
>   time=1717ms

The example I took is from here.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/springboot-appengine-standard

Comment: Have you followed the steps in the repo? What command did you run to get this error? Have you modified your `pom.xml` or `appengine-web.xml`? Please, do provide those files (with any possible private information sanitised, of course) to see if there is any mistake. 

This repository works out of the box, so, there shouldn't by any problem.

Comment: I am facing a similar kind of issue for this. I could not get it deployed to any of the environments be it standard or flexible.  Could you please let me know the appengine-web.xml or app.yaml file used for deploying to appengine flex env. I could atleast try that.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this exception since some versions of Spring Boot > 2.0.0. I don't know exactly what it means... but the application should normally run on the Google Cloud Platform...

Answer (score 0):

I just update components the gcloud

```
gcloud components list
```

[image: components update available]

```
sudo gcloud components update
```

[image: after update]

I had before update jetty-9.3.18.v20170406

[image]

I have after update: jetty-9.4.14.v20181114

[image]

PD: Sorry for my grammar, my native language is Spanish.